# How to avoid a page break before start of bibliography?

Tags: latex

I am in the progress of writing an expose for my master thesis. One point in the expose is an overview of literature. To save my time and work I use bibtex to create that chapter. The thing I want to change now is that latex starts a new page for the bibliography which is an enormous overhead in a four page document.

The, I think, relevant parts from my document are:

```
\documentclass [ fontsize = 12pt,
                 paper = a4,
                 paper = portrait,
                 twoside = false,
                 headsepline,
                 twocolumn = false,
                 numbers=noenddot
                ]{scrartcl}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\begin{document}
%
    \include{text}
    \nocite{*}
    \singlespacing
    \bibliography{literature}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

I am using biblatex. This solved the problem:

```
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\printbibliography
\endgroup
```

Comment: According to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294090/) (see David Carlisle's comment), it is not recommended to go this way... It may help in some situations, but not in others.